# add javascript onclick function

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick

I have problem with onclick, when I wan't send argument to a function ,argument always send to function same(same as last argument).What is my bug?

```
    var N = 5;
    var btns = [];
    for(var opt = 0 ; opt < N ; ++opt){ 
        var resp = "option #" + opt; 

        var options = document.createElement('input'); 
        options.setAttribute('type' , 'button'); 
        options.setAttribute('value' , resp); 
        options.addEventListener('click' , function(){ 
            doClick(resp);
        });

        btns.push(options);
    }
    var divMain = document.getElementById('mainDiv');
    for(var i = 0 ; i < btns.length ; ++i){
        divMain.appendChild(btns[i]); // add btns to main div
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [closures](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) .

Code example:

```
           var N = 5;
        var btns = [];
        for(var opt = 0 ; opt < N ; ++opt){ 
            var resp = "option #" + opt; 
            var resp=opt;
            var options = document.createElement('input'); 
            options.setAttribute('type' , 'button'); 
            options.setAttribute('value' , resp); 
            options.onclick=
                 (function(opt) {
                    return function() {
                         console.log("res: ",opt);
                }
                })(opt);

            btns.push(options);
        }
        var divMain = document.getElementById('mainDiv');
        for(var i = 0 ; i < btns.length ; ++i){
            divMain.appendChild(btns[i]); // add btns to main div
        }
```

In this example every click on the buttons will display diffrent value . So set your code where I write the console.log .

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare a body element in your code?

```js
var N = 5;
    var btns = [];
    for(var opt = 0 ; opt < N ; ++opt){ 
        var resp = "option #" + opt; 

        var options = document.createElement('input'); 
        options.setAttribute('type' , 'button'); 
        options.setAttribute('value' , resp); 
        options.addEventListener('click' , function(){ 
            doClick(resp);
        });

        btns.push(options);
    }
    var divMain = document.getElementById('mainDiv');
    for(var i = 0 ; i < btns.length ; ++i){
        divMain.appendChild(btns[i]); // add btns to main div
    }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id='mainDiv'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: elements add to mainDiv and onclick work but argument send for any element same.